# Creating a random play function in R

Tags: r, function

I want to create a gambling game that does the following:

It is a lottery, which asks for 5 numbers comprised between 01 and 43 and an additional number comprised between 01 and 16; the idea is that I give my 6 numbers and it tells me if I won or not.

To do so, use this code

```
Lotery = function(a,b,c,d,e,f){
  NumeroAleatorio <- matrix(1:6,   ncol = 6)
  NumeroAleatorio[1] <- sample (1:43, 1, replace= FALSE)
  for (i in 2:6) {
    if(i!=6){
      NumeroAleatorio[i] <- sample (1:43, 1, replace= FALSE)
      if(i == 2){
        while(NumeroAleatorio[i] == NumeroAleatorio[1] ){
          NumeroAleatorio[i] <- sample (1:43, 1, replace= FALSE)
        }
      }else{
        if(i == 3 ){
          while(NumeroAleatorio[i] == NumeroAleatorio[1]  || NumeroAleatorio[i] == NumeroAleatorio[2]){
            NumeroAleatorio[i] <- sample (1:43, 1, replace= FALSE)
          }
        }else{
          if(i == 4 ){
            while(NumeroAleatorio[i] == NumeroAleatorio[1] || NumeroAleatorio[i] == NumeroAleatorio[2]  || NumeroAleatorio[i] == NumeroAleatorio[3]){
              NumeroAleatorio[i] <- sample (1:43, 1, replace= FALSE)
            }
          }else{
            if(i == 5 ){
              while(NumeroAleatorio[i] == NumeroAleatorio[1] || NumeroAleatorio[i] == NumeroAleatorio[2] || NumeroAleatorio[i] == NumeroAleatorio[3]  || NumeroAleatorio[i] == NumeroAleatorio[4] ){
                NumeroAleatorio[i] <- sample (1:43, 1, replace= FALSE)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }else{
      NumeroAleatorio[6] <- sample (1:16, 1, replace= FALSE)
    }
  }
  ContA<-0
  ContB<-0
  ContC<-0
  ContD<-0
  ContE<-0
  ContF<-0
  for(p in 1:6){
    if(NumeroAleatorio[p] == a){
      ContA<-ContA+1
    }
    if(NumeroAleatorio[p] == b){
      ContB<-ContB+1
    }
    if(NumeroAleatorio[p] == c){
      ContC<-ContC+1
    }
    if(NumeroAleatorio[p] == d){
      ContD<-ContD+1
    }
    if(NumeroAleatorio[p] == e){
      ContE<-ContE+1
    }
    if(NumeroAleatorio[p] == f){
      ContF<-ContF+1
    }
  }
  if(ContA==0 || ContB==0 || ContC==0 || ContD==0 || ContE==0 || ContF==0){
    return(data.frame("Resultado", NumeroAleatorio, "Numero escogido",  a, b, c, d, e, f,  "No Ganaste"))
  }else{
    return(data.frame("Resultado", NumeroAleatorio, "Numero escogido",  a, b, c, d, e, f, "Ganaste"))
  }
}
Lotery(20,15,3,45,9,8)
```

It seems to work, but I want to know if I can make things simpler because I think the code is too long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may not be following your code, but it looks like you randomly select 6 numbers and compare them to the numbers submitted. None of the first 5 should match, but the 6th can match one of the first 5. If that is correct then this will generate the random 6 numbers:

```
NumeroAleatorio <- c(sample.int(43, 5, replace=FALSE), sample.int(16, 1))
```

To compare this to the submitted values, just use

```
NumeroAleatorio == comp
```

All FALSE indicates no matches. Any TRUE values indicate a match at that position.